# Displaying an image on Unity's timeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, storyboard, display, timeline

I am looking to create a Unity timeline tool that will display images onscreen in the manor of a story board, one after another, I have the display part down but I would love to be able to preview the image that is being shown on the timeline itself 
[image]

any tips or pointer you can give me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the object that contains the PlayableDirector your scene hierarchy.
2. Select "Preview" in the timeline and,
3. Use the "Scrubber" (the white vertical line) to move through the timeline sequence.

The "Game" and "Scene" window will both display the animation while out of play mode.